# Triggering an event when a css value changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, short

How can I call a function when a specific CSS variable changes (eg: the height of a particular div), using jquery?

Comment: What event makes the "variable" change in CSS?  How does the height change?  Is it dragged/maximized?

Comment: The height is changed by another jQuery command that ripples through the document. The trouble is that the changes don't propogate instantly. I only want the lower stages to update when their parent wrappers are ready.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "native" solution for this. If you're strictly using jQuery for manipulation of css propertys, a function **hook** or (*duck punshing*) is your best shot:

```
(function($) {
    var _oldcss = $.fn.css;
    $.fn.css = function() {
        if( typeof arguments[0] === 'string' ) {
            console.log('css property ', arguments[0], ' is about to change for elem: ', this);
        }

        return _oldcss.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}(jQuery));
```

This of course is incomplete. If `arguments[0]` is an `object` you would need to iterate over the key/values. But this is the basic principle.

The good thing about this solution is, that even `.height()` will call `.css()`. So

```
$('div:eq(2)').height(55);
```

would trigger **css property height is about to change for elem: [div#custom-header]**

Comment: I see, many thanks. I'm amazed there is no native option though. I was looking for something a bit like .resize();

Answer (score 0):

http://darcyclarke.me/development/detect-attribute-changes-with-jquery/ Has some plugin approach as well with quirks for different browsers.  It mimics the DOMAttrModified event across all browsers.